# How to solve "no such file or directory" when trying to run aarch64-gnu-linux-g++ (64-bit version) on 64-bit Ubuntu Linux O/S?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

The title I think says it all. Originally I though it might be a 64-bit program running on a 32-bit O/S - not the case as far as I can see.

yoctoadm@kickseed:/ntg6src/source/packages/sdk_armv8/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-gnu-linux$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

// uname -a output
yoctoadm@kickseed:/ntg6src/source/packages/sdk_armv8/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-gnu-linux$ uname -a
Linux kickseed 4.4.0-165-generic #193-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 17 17:42:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

// file aarch64-gnu-linux-g++ output
yoctoadm@kickseed:/ntg6src/source/packages/sdk_armv8/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-gnu-linux$ file aarch64-gnu-linux-g++
aarch64-gnu-linux-g++: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /ntg6sdk, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0bc9f03b2a2bee373f6ec3c85527230243579763, stripped

// no such file or directory error
yoctoadm@kickseed:/ntg6src/source/packages/sdk_armv8/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-gnu-linux$ ls
aarch64-gnu-linux-addr2line  aarch64-gnu-linux-dwp      aarch64-gnu-linux-gcc-nm      aarch64-gnu-linux-gdb      aarch64-gnu-linux-nm       aarch64-gnu-linux-size
aarch64-gnu-linux-ar         aarch64-gnu-linux-elfedit  aarch64-gnu-linux-gcc-ranlib  aarch64-gnu-linux-gprof    aarch64-gnu-linux-objcopy  aarch64-gnu-linux-strings
aarch64-gnu-linux-as         aarch64-gnu-linux-g++      aarch64-gnu-linux-gcov        aarch64-gnu-linux-ld       aarch64-gnu-linux-objdump  aarch64-gnu-linux-strip
aarch64-gnu-linux-c++filt    aarch64-gnu-linux-gcc      aarch64-gnu-linux-gcov-dump   aarch64-gnu-linux-ld.bfd   aarch64-gnu-linux-ranlib
aarch64-gnu-linux-cpp        aarch64-gnu-linux-gcc-ar   aarch64-gnu-linux-gcov-tool   aarch64-gnu-linux-ld.gold  aarch64-gnu-linux-readelf
yoctoadm@kickseed:/ntg6src/source/packages/sdk_armv8/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-gnu-linux$ ./aarch64-gnu-linux-g++
bash: ./aarch64-gnu-linux-g++: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables weren't setup correctly. It was necessary to "source" the environment file, which exports the correct environment variables.